# Is there an interpretation for this classic identity?

Tags: calculus, geometry, sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different methods to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2)

$\sum \frac{1}{n^2}= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

There are a few proofs for that fact but can anybody see why is it "really" true? Talking in geometric terms for example.

Comment: There are some relatively geometric proofs here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2

Comment: I am voting to close.

Comment: When you want to know that it is "really" true you usally look at the analytic proof not the geometric interpretation.

Comment: @Qiaouchu Yuan: Thank you. I didn't know this question was suggested already.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Even though there are many proofs, there should be room for an intuitive explanation, a 'why' answer is more than just 'how'. Would a rewording of the question to that effect be a question not likely to be closed? Naively $\pi$ has something to do with circles, and the summation not at all, and that warrants a human explanation in addition to the algebraic directions for the path between them.

Comment: @Mitch: by the OP's own admission it sounds like the previous thread answered his question, more or less. The OP is free to edit or re-ask the question and describe what is not satisfactory about the proofs in the other thread.